# Is "it will have to wait" an idiom?

Tags: idioms

> I haven't given up on my dream to study in Australia again, but for now, **it will have to wait**.

In this sentence, is "it will have to wait" an idiom? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an idiom.  It's meaning is literal

> **Not now**
>   **Not for now**

Whether or not it's followed up and gets discussed / decided / acted upon later is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *x will [just] have to wait* is a common saying (I don't think it's an [idiom](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/idiom), per se). It means that *x* (in this case, studying in Australia again) is not happening immediately, either out of necessity (it can't happen yet) or choice (someone chose something to happen instead of it). It might happen in the future.

The phrase is also often used as *[he/she/they/[name]] will [just] have to wait*, with a similar meaning: that they can't get something they want right now.